# How to display computed values during a repeater's data binding events?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, repeater

I have a repeater in a WebForm webpage which produced rows for an html table. The table's columns display bound values from the source like `<%# Eval("name") %>`. One html column will display a computed value for every row. Value not bound to any columns from the data source. The value is computed during the repeater's OnItemDataBound event. I don't want to create a dummy column in the source for the purpose of showing it only.

How do I display these values when the page is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a protected property or field in the code, you should than be able to access it inside the:
 `<%# RunningTotal %>`

```
Protected int RunningTotal {get; set;}


void OnItemDataBound(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   RunningTotal += ....
}
```